# How can I count rows matching criteria for each week in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table which stores ticket requests, and records both a requested and resolved date.

I want to craft a query that will show historically, for each week, how many unresolved tickets there were in the system.

The problem is if I use the requested date as a group criteria, then tickets that went unresolved more than one week are not counted twice. I want to make sure that any ticket that is unresolved for longer than my group size, contributes its count more than once as needed.

For example, with the following data:

```
id  requested   resolved
==  ==========  ==========
1   2015-07-01  2015-07-02
2   2015-07-01  NULL
3   2015-07-08  2015-07-10
4   2015-07-08  NULL
```

The first (26) and second week (27) each have two requests. Each week has one resolved and one unresolved request, so the result of the query should show 1 unresolved for the first week, and 2 unresolved for the second. *(Items with a resolution date in a future week also count as unresolved, but for the purposes of simplifying this example, I'm only showing null dates.)*

I'd like the result to show:

```
year   week    # unresolved
====   ====    ============
2015   26      1
2015   27      2
```

The query I have so far:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(requested) `year`,
    WEEK(requested, 5) `week`,
    COUNT(id) `# unresolved`
FROM
    tickets
WHERE
    WEEK(requested) < WEEK(resolved)
    OR resolved IS NULL
GROUP BY `Year`, `Week`;
```

Only shows 1 unresolved ticket per week:

```
year  week  # unresolved  
====  ====  ============
2015  26    1               
2015  27    1
```

What should I be looking at to modify this query appropriately?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90782/1/0

**Edit:**

As additional info, this is a relatively simple query when providing it with any specific week to examine:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) `# unresolved`
FROM
    tickets
WHERE
    WEEK(requested) <= WEEK('2015-07-01')
    AND
    (
        WEEK(resolved) > WEEK('2015-07-01')
        OR resolved IS NULL
    );
```

By changing the input week, it is possible to obtain the number of unresolved tickets for any week of interest. My goal is to create a query that will group all available data by week, rather than modify this query for single-week results.

Comment: @Strawberry http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90782/1/0

Comment: Good, but this data is a bit sparse. Are you sure it's adequately representative of the problem?

Comment: @believeme Week 26 starts June 29 and goes through July 5 (using WEEK(x,5) syntax); week 27 starts July 6 and goes through July 12. In the two examples will resolved dates, they resolve during the same week and therefore shouldn't be counted for this query.

Comment: @JYelton I got you, I deleted my comment already.... ;)

Comment: @Strawberry I agree it is sparse. I am fairly sure with a bit of prompting via answers/comments, I'll be able to apply a solution to the more complex version. At the moment my Google-fu and memory are failing me.

Comment: Why would you have 2 unresolved for the second week when you have already 1 resolved for that week based on your example, both weeks already have 1 resolved and 1 unresolved?

Comment: @believeme The concept of the query is to provide a way to count the cumulative totals of unresolved tickets in any given week. Managers want to be able to see trend data that shows what the number of unresolved issues is doing from week to week. In reality these tickets can span months of time, so they are interested in seeing, for every week, how many were still in the queue that week.

Comment: So unresolved ticket opened on 2015-01-01 would count 52 times on 2015-12-31?

Comment: @MrCleanX An unresolved ticket opened on 2015-01-01 would count once per week. If that was the unresolved ticket in the system, then all 52 weeks of the year would show 1. So that same ticket would be counted each week, but each row of the result is intended to just be a single week's "unresolved tickets this week" value. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Your sample data would be better if it had such a ticket - one that was resolved on a different week from when it was requested.  That would have caused all the suggested answers to fail (except for mine :-).

Comment: So if a ticket was resolved 3 weeks after it was opened, then it would add to the count for those 3 weeks - even though it was subsequently resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: I am showing my thought process, but you only need the final query in this answer)

(Note2: Check the [sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2643c/1))

I would look at the ticket requested and ticket resolved as two different types of events, so

```
select requested eventDate, 1 ticketChange from table
```

would give me a 1 count for each requested ticket  and

```
select resolved eventDate, -1 ticketChange from table
```

would give me a -1 count for each resolved ticket.  If I do a union of those two queries, I would get a list of dates with a +1 and a -1 for whether a ticket was added or resolved.  So I can get a total unresolved, per week by doing

```
    select year(eventDate) myYear, week(eventDate) myWeek, sum(ticketChange) totTicketChange
    from (select requested eventDate, 1 ticketChange from table union all
          select resolved eventDate, -1 ticketChange from table where resolved is not null)
    group by year(eventDate) asc, week(eventDate) asc
```

But since you need a cumulative total, then I would define a variable @unresolvedCount and increment it as I go through the select rows:

```
set @unresolvedCount := 0;
select myYear, myWeek, (@unresolvedCount := @unresolvedCount + totTicketChange) unresolved
  from (select year(eventDate) myYear, week(eventDate) myWeek, sum(ticketChange) totTicketChange
          from (select requested eventDate, 1 ticketChange from tickets union all
                select resolved eventDate, -1 ticketChange from tickets where resolved is not null) TicketEvents
 group by year(eventDate) asc, week(eventDate) asc) TicketCummulative
```

This does exactly what you want.  I have checked it with the fiddle noted above, and I would be surprised if you can find a more efficient algorithm to do what you are trying to do.  I would also suggest that you run each inner query by itself, to see its results, and work your way out.  That will give you insight into how it works.

If you want to get the results for only a particular time period, say the current year, there are three different ways to do it depending on what you want.  If you want to count **only** the tickets that were requested during this time period, that is, for example, you don't want to count tickets that were requested last year even if they are still unresolved or even if they got resolved this year, then you would change the innermost query to read:

```
select requested eventDate, 1 ticketChange from tickets where requested >= '2015-01-01' union all
select resolved eventDate, -1 ticketChange from tickets where requested >= '2015-01-01' and resolved is not null
```

If you want to count tickets that were either requested or resolved in the given time period, then  you would change the innermost query to read:

```
select requested eventDate, 1 ticketChange from tickets where requested >= '2015-01-01' union all
select resolved eventDate, -1 ticketChange from tickets where resolved is not null and resolved >= '2015-01-01'
```

If you want to count all tickets, as long as they were requested or resolved in the current time period, or if they are still unresolved (even if they are 3 years old), then you would have to put the test for the date, at the very end of the complete query, letting the inner queries process all tickets.

```
... group by year(eventDate) asc, week(eventDate) asc) TicketCummulative where myYear >= 2015 and myWeek >= 1
```

Comment: i believe he require mysql not sql server

Comment: @Devy - This is MySql.  But I do work with both MySql and SqlServer, so it is conceivable that I mistakenly mixed in some SqlServer syntax.  I don't think so, but it's possible.

Comment: @Devy - I have checked the syntax against MySql in a fiddle and resolved some minor issues.  Also, I forgot to tag you on some comments I added to your solution.

Comment: JYelton - please do check my answer and let me know.  As for the downvotes, I downvoted two or three of the answers because I tested them and saw that they failed - as such they are not useful and should be downvoted.  Mostly, they failed to deal with tickets that were resolved in a different week than they were requested.  I think Devy, who was on here before, downvoted my answer and a couple others, mine because she mistakenly thought it was not MySql code at all.  I have tested my answer, adding multi-week tickets to the data, and it works really well.  Let me know.

Comment: JYelton - basically, what you have here is an UNPIVOT problem.  You want to use two columns as rows of data where the requested column hits the total unresolved with a +1, on the date requested, and the resolved column hits the total unresolved with -1, on the date resolved, not the date that ticket was requeste.  Unfortunately, MySql does not have an UNPIVOT, so the **only** way I believe exists to do what you want is to do this UNION ALL.

Comment: This appears to do mostly what I need. I've ran this against several sets of data and it works very well. There's a minor issue where a ticket that is resolved in week n will contribute its count to that week, but that's not a big deal considering the overall scope of the query.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the Unresolved into a MySQL veriable like the following

```
set @preCount = 0;
select ticketsB.Year, ticketsB.Week,
    IF(@preCount=0, @preCount:=Unresolved, @preCount:=@preCount+Unresolved) as Unresolved from (
SELECT
    YEAR(requested) `Year`,
    WEEK(requested, 5) `Week`,
    count(id) `Unresolved`
FROM
    tickets
WHERE
    WEEK(requested) < WEEK(resolved)
    OR resolved IS NULL
GROUP BY `Year`, `Week`) as ticketsB
```

See results here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90782/61

Basically, you storing the previous unresolved count into a local veriable and then adding to the next row unresolved count based what's in the variable.

Comment: This also does not work.  Change the resolved date of the first row to 7/10, and you get 2 and 3 instead of 2 and 2 which is what you should get.  Basically, your query does not cover the fact that items may be resolved in entirely different weeks from when they were requested. And so on that week when they get resolved, they bring the cummulative total unresolved down by 1.

Comment: @Anon316 That's how it should be, because the next week is not considered as resolved, as the OP says "Items with a resolution date in a future week also count as unresolved".

Comment: no, if ticket 1 was requested on week 26 and resolved on week 27, then on week 26 you have 2 unresolved tickets (numbers 1 and 2).  Your query gets that right.  But on week 27, you still only have 2 unresolved tickets(numbers 2 and 4), because both 1 and 3 have been resolved by week 27.  Yes, OP says Items with a resolution date count as unresolved.  But when you get to that week when they do get resolved, then they should stop counting as unresolved.  Your query does not do this.  So on week 27, your query still gives 3 unresolved when it should be giving 2.

Comment: Did you read OP's comment? Here is a quote "In reality these tickets can span months of time, so they are interested in seeing, for every week, how many were still in the queue that week", so I believe my query resolves this issue.

Comment: I do not mean to give offense, but the quote you give is exactly what your query fails on.  If a ticket spans even one week, much less months, your query gives the wrong results.  Try in your fiddle to change ticket one to being resolved on week 27.  You will see that it is **never** counted as resolved, not in week 26 and not in week 27 either.

Comment: JYelton - I think @believeme and I are understanding your question differently.  Could you look at this and tell us what's up?  I could be misunderstanding what you mean by wanting a cumulative total of unresolved tickets.

Comment: @Anon316 Yes, sorry I've been away a bit. I did not intend for this to be so confusing. (Also I noticed all the rampant downvotes going on, including on the question!) If there's only one ticket in the system, and it is requested on week 1 and resolved on week 10, then the counts for weeks 1-9 will all be 1 (there's 1 unresolved ticket during those weeks). The results for week 10 will be 0, because that ticket was resolved and there are no other tickets in the system. If a ticket is opened during week 11, and has no resolution during that week, the count for week 11 will again be 1.

Answer (score 1):

Well sparse data sets deserve sparse answers, so here's another to think about...

```
SELECT WEEK(x.requested) wk
     , COUNT(y.id) 
  FROM tickets x 
  JOIN tickets y 
   ON y.id <= x.id 
  AND y.resolved IS NULL 
WHERE x.resolved IS NULL 
GROUP 
   BY WEEK(x.requested);
```

Comment: sorry, this also fails if a ticket spans a week or more.  If ticket 1 in his data is changed to be resolved in week 27, this query still gives 1 and 2 as the result for weeks 26 and 27, but the result should be 2 and 2.  For week 26, the result should be 2, instead of 1, because at week 26 the two existing tickets (id = 1 and 2) are still unresolved.

Comment: Like I said, your data set is inadequate to the task of describing the problem

Comment: Apologies for simplifying the data perhaps too much. Your solution works to the extent that resolutions are null, and I've modified your query to handle when resolutions are populated. Still working through it, and will post more when I can.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a matter of perspective. You'll need to feed the query a reporting date/week.

```
SELECT
    YEAR(requested) `Year`,
    WEEK(requested, 5) `Week`,
    COUNT(id) `Qty Unresolved`
FROM
    tickets
WHERE
    WEEK('2015-07-08') <= WEEK(resolved)
    or resolved IS NULL
GROUP BY `Year`, `Week`;
```

Comment: if he did this he will need to loop all period weeks and execute separated query for each week